# Fine intercept of stress strain curve with 0.2% yield line

Tags: r, plot, line

I am wanting to find the point of intercept between my Stress-Strain curve from a tensile test and the 0.2% offset line.

I am using plot() and lines() to graph this curve and line. The Stress-Strain curve is imported from a csv that contains the raw test data for stress (y axis) and strain (x axis). Below is the code snippet

```
TH_1_frame <- data.frame(TH_1_Strain, TH_1_Stress) # the x and y data for stress strain curve

Offset <- 0.002

TH_1_Stress02 <- TH_1_Mod*1000*(TH_1_Strain  - Offset) # TH_1_Mod is the elastic modulus and the gradient of the straight line
TH_1_Strain02 <- TH_1_Strain + Offset

TH_1_02frame <- data.frame(TH_1_Strain02, TH_1_Stress02) # the x and y for the 0.2% offset line

plot(TH_1_Strain, TH_1_Stress)
lines(TH_1_Strain02, TH_1_Stress02) # plotting the curve and line
```

Attached is the output of the plot, I am unsure how I would go about mathematically finding the intercept seen in this plot.

Thanks
[image]

Tried my best to find the data around this intercept. Can attach the csv if anyone would like.

```
dput( TH_1_Strain[9450:9500])
c(0.01567022254, 0.01566837231, 0.01566786692, 0.0156739677, 
0.01566912234, 0.01566456631, 0.01567340766, 0.01567904775, 0.01568320269, 
0.0156837975, 0.01568157723, 0.01568231732, 0.0156824626, 0.01568279291, 
0.01568822314, 0.01569599782, 0.01569751774, 0.01569260284, 0.01569438353, 
0.01569401845, 0.01569528257, 0.01570160811, 0.01570275302, 0.01571064318, 
0.01570881406, 0.01570606853, 0.01571034392, 0.01570852846, 0.01571317886, 
0.01572433362, 0.01572758953, 0.01572479432, 0.01569923262, 0.01569651316, 
0.01570669313, 0.01571742942, 0.01573171467, 0.01576093584, 0.01573084916, 
0.01569425811, 0.01570926358, 0.01572924977, 0.01574603468, 0.01575124015, 
0.01574295014, 0.0157436803, 0.0157436803, 0.01571707924, 0.01571890339, 
0.01574868957, 0.01576487596)
> 
> dput( TH_1_Stress[9450:9500])
c(785.800149043174, 785.821152259166, 785.839877152789, 785.856608787737, 
785.871061735784, 785.884019739826, 785.896123281846, 785.908297907524, 
785.918265659023, 785.930013418222, 785.937987546514, 785.943825519753, 
785.953650739404, 785.966252960625, 785.976007096618, 785.989748114491, 
786.001709124664, 786.012175190831, 786.021431012156, 786.030045986964, 
786.039230360099, 786.050835587451, 786.059236946754, 786.065715766509, 
786.072479649959, 786.076110749018, 786.079812931735, 786.083230415289, 
786.085793436822, 786.087502360865, 786.087573444522, 786.084084877311, 
786.080524861909, 786.079955463583, 786.078673770551, 786.079172085219, 
786.078673770551, 786.078104372224, 786.075469902502, 786.07333411198, 
786.072408566301, 786.075968217171, 786.081165708425, 786.085508737659, 
786.09042152975, 786.091204543582, 786.09440841163, 786.099392287379, 
786.112350291421, 786.12367081961, 786.138550998668)
```

Comment: The input is  missing.   Please show it using dput as requested by the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: My apologies, struggling to figure out dput(). there are over 30 000 data points for the curve in the csv, would it be acceptable if I attach the csv?

Comment: The idea is to provide a *minimal* problem that if solved would help you solve you original problem, not to provide large problems. Try dput(head(X, n)) where X is your data and n is sufficient number of rows to illustrate the problem.